# Code not accepting inputs from users for Centroid

Tags: java

I am currently working on a project where I need to take the user input and then use that input for a calculation for the centroid of a triangle. The length of the triangle comes from the user's input. For some reason, the formula will not accept the user input.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Centroid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // coordinate of the vertices 
        Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter variables for x1:");
        String x1 = bucky.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter variables for x2:");
        String x2 = bucky.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter variables for x3:");
        String x3 = bucky.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter variables for y1:");
        String y1 = bucky.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter variables for y2:");
        String y2 = bucky.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter variables for y3:");
        String y3 = bucky.nextLine();
        
     
      
        // Formula to calculate centroid 
        float x = (x1 + x2 + x3) / 3; 
        float y = (y1 + y2 + y3) / 3; 
      
        System.out.println("Centroid = "
        + "(" + x + ", " + y + ")"); 
    }

}
```

Comment: What do u mean the formula wont take the user input ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using String as centroid values you should use numeric variables like float integer double or short that is why your formula is not working

**Try float variables**

```
public class Centroid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // coordinate of the vertices 
        Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter variables for x1:");
        float x1 = bucky.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Please enter variables for x2:");
        float x2 = bucky.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Please enter variables for x3:");
        float x3 = bucky.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Please enter variables for y1:");
        float y1 = bucky.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Please enter variables for y2:");
        float y2 = bucky.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Please enter variables for y3:");
        float y3 = bucky.nextFloat();



        // Formula to calculate centroid 
        float x = (x1 + x2 + x3) / 3;
        float y = (y1 + y2 + y3) / 3;

        System.out.println("Centroid = "
                + "(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to divide a sum of strings.The solution is making the variables (x1, x2, x3, etc,) float; changing the: "String x1 = bucky.nextLine();" to : "float x1 = bucky.nextFloat();".

```
public class Centroid{

public static void main(String[] args) {
// coordinate of the vertices 
Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter variables for x1:");
float x1 = bucky.nextFloat();
System.out.println("Please enter variables for x2:");
float x2 = bucky.nextFloat();
System.out.println("Please enter variables for x3:");
float x3 = bucky.nextFloat();
System.out.println("Please enter variables for y1:");
float y1 = bucky.nextFloat();
System.out.println("Please enter variables for y2:");
float y2 = bucky.nextFloat();
System.out.println("Please enter variables for y3:");
float y3 = bucky.nextFloat();



// Formula to calculate centroid 
float x = (x1 + x2 + x3)/ 3; 
float y = (y1 + y2 + y3)/ 3; 

System.out.println("Centroid = "
+ "(" + x + ", " + y + ")"); 
}

}
```